# Custom Ng-Bootstrap Carousel, display image and description fields

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am attempting to customize an Angular Bootstrap Carousel! I have been able to change the layout and design a bit, such that I have two columns, on the right the image and on the left some text with some custom arrows on either side.

I am trying to achieve two things: **firstly**, is there another (more efficient?) way to list the images? Currently my gallery.ts has the list of images to be displayed, for now its fine but there will be a lot of images so I was wondering if there was a way to maybe put it in a separate file and pull the information from there?

Below is my **gallery.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    images = [
        //"assets/images/1.jpg",
        "assets/images/12.jpg",
        "assets/images/18.jpg",
        "assets/images/15.jpg",
        "assets/images/11.jpg",
        "assets/images/13.jpg",
        "assets/images/7.jpg",
        "assets/images/16.jpg"
    ];

    constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
        // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
        config.interval = 10000;
        config.wrap = false;
        config.keyboard = true;
        config.pauseOnHover = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

**Secondly**, I need to change the text that is on the left column dynamically along with the image. For every slide there should be a date and a short description displayed. Any ideas?

Below is my **gallery.html**:

```html
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
        <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_img">
                <figure>
              <img [src]="img" alt="Random first slide">
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_description">
    <div class="description_date">
     August 20th 2016 
     <!-- To be displayed dynamically with every with slide {{ img_date ?? }} -->
    </div>
    <div class="description_text">
     <!-- To be displayed dynamically with every with slide {{ img_description ?? }} -->
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem.
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue?

Comment: just use an array of object, e.g. [{image:"assets/images/12.jpg",date:"Ago 17",text:"lorem ipsum"},{image:"assets/images/13.jpg",date:"Sep 17",text:"lorem ipsum"}..] and in the loop use [src]="data.image",{{data.date}} and {{data.text}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 2 points from your question:

- I was wondering if there was a way to maybe put it in a separate file and pull the information from there?

  - Yes, you can have this information in a json file on your server... or better in a database somewhere; in my example i placed the file in a json file.
- I need to change the text that is on the left column dynamically along with the image. For every slide there should be a date and a short description displayed

  - You can have an object instead of array of images, here you can have any number of fields that you actually need in your front end

relevant **JSON** file:

```
{ "imgArray": [
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/501/900/500", "heading" :"first", "description":"first heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/502/900/500", "heading" :"h2", "description":"second heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/503/900/500", "heading" :"h3", "description":"third heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/504/900/500", "heading" :"h4", "description":"fourth heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/505/900/500", "heading" :"h5", "description":"fifth heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/506/900/500", "heading" :"h6", "description":"sixth heading's description"},
{"img": "https://picsum.photos/id/507/900/500", "heading" :"h7", "description":"seventh heading's description"}
]
}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let slide of images; index as i">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 '>
                <div class="description_date">
                    <h1>{{slide.heading}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="description_text">
                    {{slide.description}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6'>
                <div class="gallery_img">
                    <figure>
                        <img [src]="slide.img" alt="Random first slide">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as dataJSON from './data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-carousel-config',
  templateUrl: './carousel-config.html',
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]  // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers
  ,styles: [` 
  .img-fluid{ min-width:100%}
  .row{background:lightgray;}
  .description_date, .description_text { padding:5%; }
  `]
})
export class NgbdCarouselConfig {
  images:any[] = []
  readJSON = dataJSON;

    constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
        // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
        config.interval = 10000;
        config.wrap = false;
        config.keyboard = true;
        config.pauseOnHover = false;

        this.images = this.readJSON.default.imgArray;
    }
}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyfcfs-p7o9mu)

Comment: What is the purpose of 'default' here? I get this error "Property 'default' does not exist "

Comment: @kontenurban, default is needed to read the array from within the object which is in the JSON file... if you use the same structure as my JSON file, you wouldn't get this error - if you have a different structure, get to the array as per your structure

Comment: I changed the strucuture to match yours but that doesn't seem to make a difference! This is the full error!  ERROR in src/app/content-component/gallery/gallery.component.ts(22,37): error TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type '{ "imgArray": { "img": string; "date": string; "description": string; }[]; }'.

Comment: your stackblitz doesn't work... it says: `Import error, can't find file:
./app/app.module`

Comment: I fiugured it out! Your method of importing the arrray just didn't work at all, so this is how I did it! `import  { imgArray } from './gallery-data.json';` Then, `images : any[] = [];`  and this  `this.images = imgArray;`